# How can I copy data of field in other field which is located in other app with different name django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models and In first app there is field name current_bill and in Second app there is field name is previous_bill I want to copy data of current_bill in previous_bill How can I copy it ?

***meter_detail/models.py***

```
Meter(models.Model):
     current_bill=MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=True, default_currency='INR')
```

***bill_detail/models.py***

```
Bill(models.Model):
     previous_bill=MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default_currency='INR')
```

I want copy of value which I enter in current_bill and save in Model Bill I tried this

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.previous_outstanding = self.current_outstanding.previous_outstanding
    super(Bill, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But Its not working please give me solution for copy field

Comment: I think you need to load the Meter object in your save() method if you want to copy it's data to the Bill object. It's not clear how `self.current_outstanding.previous_outstanding` is referring to the Meter object. Can you add more of the code please?

Comment: I already import from meter_details.models import Meter in Bill

Comment: Ok. Can you please add more code to your question, so people can see how Bill is related to Meter? i.e. where is `current_outstanding.previous_outstanding` defined?